# Why does different layout_weights not work in table layout?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-tablelayout

I have a problem using layout_weight on TableLayout. It all works well when all rows have a `layout_weight` of 1:

[image: Working layout]

The result is *acceptable* but not perfect. So I tried to add `layout_weight` to make the first row a little smaller and the last 4 rows a little bigger. But the result is more the surprising:

[image: first try with layout_weight]

This is so wrong it hurts. I also tried to make the first row smaller and leave the other as they are. That too gives a wacky result:

[image: second try with layout_weight]

Any ideas what can trigger this faulty behaviour? Any head ups? Any well known problems to look out for?

**Source Code:**

The XML Sources are rather complex with included for portrait and landscape so I rather link the repository:

- [calculator.xml](http://sourceforge.net/p/uiq3/code/6636/tree/trunk/Java/FX-603P/Droid/res/layout-port/calculator.xml)
- [buttons_1.xml](http://sourceforge.net/p/uiq3/code/6636/tree/trunk/Java/FX-603P/Droid/res/layout/buttons_1.xml)
- [buttons_2.xml](http://sourceforge.net/p/uiq3/code/6636/tree/trunk/Java/FX-603P/Droid/res/layout/buttons_2.xml)
- [styles.xml](http://sourceforge.net/p/uiq3/code/6636/tree/trunk/Java/FX-603P/Droid/res/values/styles.xml)
- [dimens.xml](http://sourceforge.net/p/uiq3/code/6636/tree/trunk/Java/FX-603P/Droid/res/values/dimens.xml)
- [Calculator_Button_5.java](http://sourceforge.net/p/uiq3/code/6636/tree/trunk/Java/Calculator/Droid/src/main/java/net/sourceforge/uiq3/calculator/Calculator_Button_5.java)

**Working version:**

Last not least a picture of a older working version. The `android:layout_weight` where: 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 5, 5, 5, 5

[image: working version]

Yes, I now, never touch working code. But I had memory problems (  [android.widget.LinearLayout](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/LinearLayout.html) and [android.widget.RelativeLayout](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/RelativeLayout.html) are real memory hogs) and changed some layouts to [android.view.ViewGroups](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewGroup.html). Note hat the buttons are special as they have a larger click area to make it easier to hit them despite there small size.

Comment: What's wrong in the first image? I like it! Except the numbers not vertically centered, but this is really trivial to fix...

Comment: Anyway, it would be helpful if you also posthe styles `style='@style/Button.#'` and the custom component `net.sourceforge.uiq3.calculator.Calculator_Button_5_`

Comment: I noticed that you use single quote (**'**) instead of double quotes (**"**)... is it even possible? Well, I guess, yes, or you would have had a bunch of errors in your IDE. Or are you working in a text editor all the time (I noticed some fancy **VIM** footers)?

Comment: As I said: it is acceptable. But the first row take to much height. Pixel which are missing in all the other rows. I add a screen shot to show what it should look like

Comment: Is the "first row" the one with SHIFT, 2nd, ALPHA, ...? Or is it the "LCD"?

Comment: @FrankN.Stein added links to style.xml and Calculator_Button_5.java. And yes you can use ' or " makes no difference for XML (or HTML for that matter). With first row im mean SHIFT…. Mind you: the LCD is a row as well. But not a *button row* ;-)

Comment: @FrankN.Stein This is tricky as there are multiple dimension files for layout, portrait. I add the main one. But you said something about padding. Anything i should look out?

Comment: Padding or margin that coud inflate some extra height and make it  bigger than necessary (I'd look in the dimens.xml for some oversized dimension, maybe - or add another value to use for the first row only). Anyway, I was trying to make a weight-only calculation... There are 6 rows; something like 17*5 + 15 (85% + 15% = 100%) could go? so 5 rows would be SLIGHTLY  bigger than the firs one. OR you could make 18*5 + 10  (90% + 10% = 100%) (The 5 rows below would be MUCH bigger - nearly the double respect to the first row)

Comment: The old design (which I also like) suggests a 15, 17, 17, 17, 17, 17 weight asset (only considering the 6 rows, as grouped in a LinearLayout or some of its descendants)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/59067/discussion-between-martin-and-frank-n-stein).

Comment: In "merge" change layout_height to fill_parent or match_parent.

Comment: @cyanide If I did that Android Lint would immediately tell me otherwise. The general suggestion when `layout_weight` is involved is to set the expanded dimension to 0dp and let the layout expand the view.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @Frank N. Stein I got some new inside into `android:layout_weight` which I like to share with you

**1) It is a float and its sum up to 100%**

Most of the samples you will find in the internet show [android:layout_weight](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/LinearLayout.LayoutParams.html#attr_android:layout_weight) as an integer. But really [android.widget.LinearLayout.LayoutParams.weight](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/LinearLayout.LayoutParams.html#weight) is a float.

However, bare floats are the poor cousin of the XML parser and they are a bit tricky to use. First they don't have there own XML tag so you have to use the generic `<item>` tag:

```
<resources>
  <item name='Row_Weight_0' type='fraction'>7.0</item>
  <item name='Row_Weight_1' type='fraction'>9.0</item>
  <item name='Row_Weight_2' type='fraction'>12.0</item>
</resources>
```

Then they are not called `float` but `fractions` and must later be references as such:

```
  <LinearLayout
    android:layout_weight="@fraction/Row_Weight_2"
    style='@style/Row'
  >
```

So you might still want to use integers for its simpler syntax. But remember that they will be scaled to %. For example if you set your `android:layout_weight` to {1, 1, 2} they will be transformed to {25%, 25%, 50%}.

I used `android:layout_weight` of {2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 5, 5, 5, 5} which gives a `android:layout_weightSum` of *37*. A prime number. Not a good start and bound to give you rounding problems. @Frank N. Stein suggested to choose your `android:layout_weight` so that your `android:layout_weightSum` becomes a *multiple* of 100%. i.E. 10, 100 or 1000.

**2) I used a Table Layout**

One might think a table layout would be perfect for rows and columns of buttons. It turns out I was wrong. Look at the following pictures. One uses [android.widget.TableLayout](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TableLayout.html) and [android.widget.TableRow](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TableRow.html) the other plain old [android.widget.LinearLayout](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/LinearLayout.html). Nothing else changed. Just a `%s /TableRow/LinearLayout/g` and a `%s /TableLayout/LinearLayout/g`

[image: TableLayout with TableRow]
[image: Linear Layout with Linear Layout]

That is a significant difference. The first a disaster the second precisely what I want. So the answer is to my questions is:

**There is a problem with [android.widget.TableRow](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TableRow.html) when the rows need to be shrunk to fit the screen! Use [android.widget.LinearLayout](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/LinearLayout.html) instead.**